# Link function for exponential regression

Tags: r, regression, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution, link-function

I have a dataset with an exponential relationship that I'm linearizing before fitting with code like this:

```
glm(log(y) ~ log(x), family = gaussian)
```

I'm trying to decide between using `link = "identity"` and `link = "log"` with the Gaussian distribution. For my data, a model fit with the log link has a very slightly lower AIC ($0.6$), but the model fits look similar.

**MODEL DIAGNOSITIC PLOTS: link = "log"**
[image: link = "log"]

**MODEL DIAGNOSITIC PLOTS: link = "identity"**
[image: link = "identity"]

Comment: Do you have a theoretical reason to believe it's one or the other?

Comment: @AlexJ only that the values for y cannot go below zero, which I would support the log link.

Comment: To be clear, are you using `glm(log(y) ~ log(x), family = gaussian(link=log)`? That is, modelling log y with a log link?

Comment: Without knowing anything further, they both look OK to me. Note that you've already log-transformed the data, so you've solved the problem of y not going less than zero. The difference between identity and log link, is also that identity link has a linear increase in log(y) for a unit increase in log(x), whereas log link has a percentage increase in log(y) for a unit increase in log(x). you may have some theory suggesting one or the other

Comment: unrelated to the question, but not gaussian plus a log link, generally, _does not imply the response variable is > 0_. It implies the _mean_ of the response variable is > 0. For example take a Gaussian with mean 0.5, sd 1. This is something you could get from a log-link Gaussian, but it can definitely take values < 0

Comment: @DemetriPananos, yes, modeling log y with a log link is one option I was considering.

Comment: @AlexJ thanks for that helpful clarification! on the reponse mean vs all values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two approaches are similar, but different.

On the one hand, the identity link models

$$ E[\log(y) \mid X=x] = x^T \beta $$

where as the log link models

$$ \log(E[\log(y) \mid X=x]) = x^T \beta $$

(though I  imagine what you really want is $\log(E[y \mid X=x])$).  In either case, you need to determine if you want to assume the log of the outcome should satisfy the assumptions of linear regression, or if you want to model the log of the expected value as linear in the parameters (alternatively that the conditional mean is exponential).

As you're seeing, the two approaches are very similar.  In fact, the two should yield the same estimates for the $\beta$ and different intercepts (the intercept for the log link should be larger than the log linear model by as much as $\sigma^2/2$, where $\sigma^2$ is an estimate of the RMSE from the log linear model).

I don't think fit statistics should be used to determine the modelling approach.  In this specific case, the two approaches are about the same up to the value of the intercept as I've mentioned, but generally speaking the link and likelihood should be chosen based on substantive knowledge about how the phenomenon.

Comment: Thanks @Demetri. At this time, I don't think I had a strong enough understanding of the system to determine if the identity or log link models makes the most sense. But it is helpful to know that aside from the intercept, the two models should produce similar results.